# Passport.js equivalent for Python?

Tags: google-app-engine, node.js, authentication

Is there a library that allows me to quickly add login options to my Python (Google AppEngine) app, similar to Passport.js?

Answer (score 9):

I think that the Passport.js equivalent for Python is [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/).

Authlib is also shipped with integrations for Django and Flask.

Comment: this is the relevant answer as of 2019

Comment: What's the current relevant answer without a $1000/year licensing fee?

Answer (score 6):

Try: EngineAuth https://github.com/scotch/engineauth

Or SimpleAuth https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth

Or AppEngine oAuthLibrary
https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library